# Set new.html as the base file

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to set new.html as the base file for the server, but it keeps defaulting to index.html

My code is below...

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Set '/public' as the static folder.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// Set index.html as the base file
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/new.html');
});

var server = app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('Listening to requests on port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the **index** file to use as an option to `express.static()`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Set '/public' as the static folder.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {
  index: 'new.html'
}));

const server = app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('Listening to requests on port 4000');
});
```

Then, you no longer need the `/` route.

---

Alternatively, you could specify your `/` route before your static directory:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Set new.html as the base file
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/new.html');
});

// Set '/public' as the static folder.
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

const server = app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('Listening to requests on port 4000');
});
```

*Note: the file path should be `/public/new.html` rather than `/new.html`.*